# How to make a panoramic cylinder with Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, panoramas

I am trying to make a panoramic view with a panoramic photo on WebGL.
At everywhere there are examples with 8 photos and a cube but I have a photo and I want to texture inside of a cylinder and place camera to center of it. Also when I wrote "Three.js tutorial" to google, I found many examples but there is no exactly definition of functions. Can you offer me good one?

Comment: Study the examples that are similar to what you want to do, and if you get stuck, show what you have tried, and ask a specific question.

Comment: for example http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_panorama this uses 8 photos and cubic view for panorama and http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular this uses a spheric panoramic photo and a sphere. I am trying to do this with a cylinder.

Comment: Can you edit the sphere example and replace it with a `THREE.CylinderGeometry`?

Comment: I did it but of course not learning from tutorials because each example has different number of parameter. In open source code it needs 6 parameters. I should learn everything with trial-and-error method but I do not have much time. At now I am trying to texture only rectangle area of cylinder not top and bottom rounds. I could not find explanatory sources.

Comment: I will help you, but you need to learn how to figure things out for yourself. Edit the equirectangular example, set `fov = 45`, and replace the `SphereGeometry` with this: `var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 500, 500, 1000, 64, 1, true );`